# Custom Script-based Backups

Tags: windows, scripting, backup-restoration

I'm a believer in having multiple restore solutions in place for the environment I support.
I have a production backup solution for my Windows Server environment.  It includes an agent on each box and uses a standard nightly backup schedule to a cloud service of System State and File Shares.  I'm interested in creating script-based solution which writes to a large NAS we just purchased for miscellaneous and DR use.  This environment will strictly be a 2nd way of backing up and restoring certain aspects of the environment.  It will also be used to do quick one-off backups prior to any scheduled change or upgrade.  I'm making a list of services that I'd like to backup here.  So far I have:

1. Active Directory
2. DNS
3. DHCP
4. GPO's
5. Event Logs
6. Performance Counters
7. Certificates
8. Appliance server backup dumps
9. Hyper-V VM's
10. Printer Configs
11. IIS Layer 3 Switches - Configuration, Firmware, Image, DR,
    Export/Config file
12. Applications - DB dumps & application specific
    manual data dump solutions

If there is anyone else out there with this type of ad-hoc backup solution and has other services they have added to this list, please let me know.  I need to add aspects of Azure and our company's azure synchronization settings, but I'm not as up to speed in that area yet.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest that you take a note of veeam for example and s3 like Wasabi but regardless to this, product suggestions are off topic on serverfault.com

Comment: Have you considered that having two backups of the same environment, might influence each others performance. And we need more information about your storage, the file shares are they hosted on a fileserver with local disks or a NAS or SAN?

Comment: Yes, I understand Veeam is an option to run the backups I'm specifying.  I haven't decided what tool I'm going to run each backup.  I assume it will be different for each service I'm backing up.  I am not interested in backing up file shares this way.  That can be handled by are production backup environment.  This would be simple quick backups of certain datasets only that I may need to use to do quick restores like to reconfigure a replacement switch, do a quick restore of AD if there's corruption, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest something else, talking about, you could also install the Azure backup agent on your on-prem servers, and backup directly to Azure, using Azure backup.

I would stay away from a scripted backup in windows environments.

Edit

I think most things should be do-able with PowerShell, but keep in mind that powershell modules change frequently, so there is quite some maintenance required. If you search in the PowerShell community I think you can find quite some modules which can export the configuration of the various workloads you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you.  Our production backup is already cloud based and includes system states and file systems of all or servers.  What I'm trying to do is create an alternate backup of configuration information only that I may need as an administrator to bring back or replace specific things like switches, AD, appliance server configs, etc....

Comment: Ah, what we in Azure call, Infrastructure-as-Code.I will edit my post a bit.